# I renamed a Model. How can I recover my now-missing db objects?

Tags: django, django-models

My model was foo.bar.MyModel. Now it's boo.far.MyModel. The schema is the same.

boo.far.MyModel.objects.all() is now empty obviously. Is there a way to run through objects in the database and change the class that they are associated with? Some kind of search and replace of class name? It's not that many objects and this is just a test database so I'm looking to do this by hand. Not looking to use South or anything like that. I realize I could also recreate the old package/class and then migrate but I'm interested if I can fix this the nitty gritty way.

edit: I'm using non-rel backend on Google App Engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just rename model's table in the database. Table name is constructed from app label and model's class name, so MySQL query is:

```
RENAME TABLE bar_mymodel TO far_mymodel;
```

Second option is to use "db_table" model option to override default table name:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'bar_mymodel'
```

Comment: What if I'm using non-rel backend? :)

Comment: existing data is an issue with non-rel back end. Option 2 should be worth trying. Also, in option 1, need to update django_content_type entries also, if any.